# Typeorm doesnt wanna update the database

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have a **supply** table with **name** and **quantity** columns. I would expect the following code to update the quantity but it does not. Can someone correct my code please?

```
const repository = connection.getRepository('supply');
await repository.update({ quantity: 20 }, { name: 'supply1' });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try the writing the query like this:

```
connection.createQueryBuilder()
.update(Supply)
.set({ quantity: 20 })
.where('name = :name', { name: 'supply1' })
.execute();
```

In this query, Supply should be the entity, not a string. This is based on the [documentation for Update Using Query Builder](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/update-query-builder.md).

**Update:**

To use the repository.update syntax as you have used in the edited query, you should reorder the arguments.

```
const repository = connection.getRepository(SupplyEntity);
await repository.update({ name: 'supply1' }, { quantity: 20 });
// executes UPDATE supply SET quantity = 20 WHERE name = "supply1"
```

Source: [Documentation for the repository.api](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/repository-api.md)

Also, you might try to `console.log(repository)` to make sure it exists. Otherwise, you might try passing in the entity as I've done in the code sample above.

Comment: Yes I tried and this way it works. But I would like the repository version to work too since I'd like to pass a string. Any idea why the repository version does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the oreder:

```
await repository.update({ quantity: 20 }, { name: 'supply1' }); // tries to update where quantity is 20...
await repository.update( { name: 'supply1' }, { quantity: 20 }); // updates quantity
```